# Should I store number of comments/likes/dislikes in my image table?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Should I store number of `comments/likes/dislikes` in my image table by updating them after every new `like/dislike/comment` record

or

should I just query something like `Vote::where('image_id', $this->id)->where('vote', true)->count();` every time I need to know the count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really depends on the actual case (e.g. how much data you are storing and expecting) and also there are two colliding philosophies which have been seen both.

Argument one: Do not save calculable data. If you can save a chain of events (e.g. all votes), you can always deduct the totals from that. However, the drawback of that is that it might become slow on applications with much data.

Argument two: Do save the data that you need. Depending on what kind of persistency layer you are using, it might be a good idea to save the data whenever it is changed. E.g. MongoDB does have a "just store what you need" approach. Advantage: Even on applications with much data this would be with good performance as you do not have to calculate anything on the fly and can just output the number.

TL;DR: It really depends on which factors your application likely struggles more with.